# Query for finding similar interests together

Tags: mysql, relational-algebra

```
Name    Place visited

Ash     New york
Bob     New york
Ash     Chicago
Bob     Chicago
Carl    Chicago
Carl    Detroit
Dan     Detroit
```

Above is the sample table. The output should be two names who visited place together. I.e. the output should be Ash and Bob since the places visited by Ash also visited by Bob.

Output:

```
Name1  Name2

Ash    Bob
```

What is a query for this using MySQL or even relational algebra?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use `group_concat()`.  Assuming no duplicates,

```
select places, group_concat(names) as names
from (select name, group_concat(place order by place) as places
      from t
      group by name
     ) t
group by places
having count(*) > 1;
```

This will return all the names with exactly the same places on a single row.  The names will be in a comma-delimited list.